# Using gg=G in Vim to automatically tab a document when tabstop is modified

Tags: vim

Usually, one uses `gg=G` in vim to automatically tab C/C++/Java code or in fact any sort of code.

However, I changed my `tabstop` variable to be `tabstop=2` in my default settings for vim, so that whenever I tab I get the equivalent of 2 spaces instead of the default 8.

Now whenever I use `gg=G`, I get 4 tabs instead of 1 for indentation so that the spacing *looks* equivalent to before when I had tabstop=8. I just want 1 tab though. Is there a way to do this?

(I am using hard tabs only for indentation, no spaces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking is `shiftwidth`. `set sw=2` for proper indentation for your case. `:help sw`

At the same time, instead of changing `tabstop=2`, it is better to `set softtabstop=2`. Details at `:help ts`.

and for source code, usually it is good to expand `tab` as it is not preferred for source code.

You can set following settings in your `vimrc`

```
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
```

I personally prefer indentation of `4`. With `2`, it will be hard to notice the indent sometimes :)

Comment: This makes the indentation 2 spaces rather than 1 tab of length equal to two spaces. I am using hard tabs only for indentation. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Settings `tab` to other value is not a good idea, You can change the value accordingly.

Comment: @d223chen then leave `expandtab` off, but still change `shiftwidth` :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. `tabstop` refers to the length of a tab when I manually press TAB. When using `gg=G`, it uses a value of an option called "shiftwidth" instead. I `set shiftwidth=2` and it now uses 1 tab for automatic indentation instead of 4. :)